# Dropdown is not saving - MVC C# Sharing a combined class and save into another table

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I want to know how to save the following.

I am populating text fields and dropdowns with information coming from multiple classes in EF however, not sure how to save the info to another table in SQL Server.

This is an example:

```
<tr>
    <th colspan="6" >
    Product Description: <br />
    </th>
    <th colspan="6">                                                          
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.First_Table.Descriptions, new SelectList(ViewBag.GetProducts, "RowID", "Descriptions"), "Please Select", new { @class = "form-control", @id= "ddlDescription" }) 
    </th>
</tr>
```

The part above gets the product description from a query upon page load.

Now I want to save it into this table like this:

```
public ActionResult Index(tblSecond tblSecond)
{         
    string description = HttpContext.Request.Form["First_Table.Descriptions"];

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(strSQLconnection))
    {
        connection.Open();

        string sql = $"insert into tbl_insertintosql( description ) " +
                     $"Values ( '"+ description +"')";

        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
        {
            command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            connection.Close();
        }
    }

    return RedirectToAction("");
}
```

I feel like this piece of code is the issue:

```
string description = HttpContext.Request.Form["First_Table.Descriptions"];
```

Comment: **WARNING:** Your code is *dangerous*; it is wide open to SQL Injection attacks. You **need** to address this huge security flaw in your code ASAP. It's 2021, there is no reason to have not have learned from the mistakes others have made over the last few decades.

Comment: How are you  submitting your view? Could you post the whole view code pls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone wanting an answer:

You can create a model object like this and call it to your string as follows.

```
    public ActionResult Index(tblCombined model)
    {
              string descriptions = model.First_Table.Descriptions;
     }
```